# Arduino : GPRS shield not responding to AT commands

Tags: arduino, at-command, gprs

Problem : Unable to communicate with GPRS Shield 
Devices : Arduino Uno, GRPS Shield V2.0

Approach :
I am following the GPRS shield guide found here : http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V2.0

First of all I successfully installed the GPRS shield on the arduino, which I power through a DC jack and connect via USB (someone mentioned before the problem could be from lack of power to the shield so I plug in the DC jack).
The shield blinks every 3 seconds indicating it has successfully connect to the network (Freemobile France).

I successfully connected the Arduino through COM5 on my computer, I know this because I can upload the blink example from the arduino software without any problems.

So following the instructions for "test setup" on the wiki above, I upload the sketch given. I then configure the serial tool as indicated, but I am unable to type any commands in.
I then tried the online tool at http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/module-tester/

It was unable to connect to I followed their troubleshooting guide which led me to "verify the serial connection" and install putty.
I configured Putty as needed and encountered the same problem, I can't even test the serial connection because I can't type into the console.

Thank you for any help, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What kind of terminal program are you using?  If you are using the arduino serial port to send AT commands, your going to have issues with carriage return and new line characters.  When I had the same problem, I read [this article](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/all#serial-terminal-overview-) about using a terminal to communicate over a serial port.  After reading that short article, I ultimately decided to download [coolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org/).  However, I am using a mac.  You may want to use a different terminal program.

Answer (score 0):

With 7 pin with Leonardo it do not work. With 10 pin (need connect a wire) work ok.